# Ayuda Sopa de letras

Tags: java

Hola tengo un pequeño problema desde hace días que no logro resolver tengo una sopa de letras que se rellena de manera aleatoria pero debo "ocultar" las palabras de el arreglo en la sopa de letras sin que se repitan y sin que se salga del tamaño como puedo hacerlo ?

```
public class SopaLetras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sopa s = new sopa();
        s.genera(20);
    }

}
class sopa {
    String[] animal;
    //String [] caracter = new String[50];

public sopa() {
    animal = new String [] {"FOCA","TIBURON","CONEJO","RATON","GATO","PERRO","PERICO","RANA",
        "SAPO","ARDILLA","CUYO","SERPIENTE","GORILA","BALLENA","LEON","TIGRE","CABALLO",
        "BURRO","OSO","ELEFANTE"};
}
public void genera(int N){
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++) {
        int letra = (int)(Math.random()*26+65);
        System.out.print((char)letra);

}
    System.out.println();
}


}
}
```

Comment: Puedes manipular cada String del arreglo del String y cambiar las letras por algún carácter diferente por ejemplo *

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente para validar que no se requieren más elementos de los disponibles, puedes validarlo en tu método:

```
public void genera(int N) {

  if(N > animal.length) {
      System.out.print("El número máximo debe ser " + animal.length);
      return;
  } 
  ...
  ...
```

En cuanto a obtener elementos aleatoriamente del array `animal` , lo puedes realizar de esta forma usando la clase `Random`:

```
   String[] animal = new String [] {"FOCA","TIBURON","CONEJO","RATON","GATO","PERRO","PERICO","RANA",
    "SAPO","ARDILLA","CUYO","SERPIENTE","GORILA","BALLENA","LEON","TIGRE","CABALLO",
     "BURRO","OSO","ELEFANTE"};

  Random rand = new Random();
  String randomAnimal = animal[rand.nextInt(animal.length)];
```

Si deseas varios elementos puedes usar un bucle, y un array donde se vayan almancenando los elementos, pero en este caso debes revisar si el elemento existe en el array usando el método `contains()` :

```
if(animals.contains(randomAnimal)){ 
  //Ya existe!
}else{
  //No existe, agregarlo.
}
```

---

Este sería una opción para realizar la sopa de "palabras":

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class sopa {

    String[] animal;

    public sopa() {
        animal = new String[]{"FOCA", "TIBURON", "CONEJO", "RATON", "GATO", "PERRO", "PERICO", "RANA",
            "SAPO", "ARDILLA", "CUYO", "SERPIENTE", "GORILA", "BALLENA", "LEON", "TIGRE", "CABALLO",
            "BURRO", "OSO", "ELEFANTE"};
    }

    public void genera(int N) {

      //Valida que la cantidad de elementos no sea mayor al total disponible  
      if(N > animal.length) {
          System.out.print("El número máximo debe ser " + animal.length);
          return;
      } 

      //Crea arrayList para almacenar elemntos aleatorios.      
      List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       Random rand = new Random();
       String randomAnimal = animal[rand.nextInt(animal.length)]; //Obtiene elemento aleatorio
       if(animals.contains(randomAnimal)){ //¿Ya se contiene en el array?, 
          //busca nuevamente.          
          i--; //decrementa variable i.
       }else{
          //No se contiene en el array, lo agrega. 
          animals.add(randomAnimal);
       }

      }

      //Imprime array resultante.
       System.out.println("Total: " +animals.size() + " elementos: " + animals.toString());

   }
}
```